# Indicator in expectation

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose we have a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, say we have a random variable $X$ defined on this measure space. My question now is; if we have an event say $F \in \mathcal{F}$ is it in general true that:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ X \mathbb{1}_{\{F\}} \right] = \mathbb{E} [X]P(F).$$

Obviously we have $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{\{F\}}\right]=P(F)$ but is the above relation also true?

Comment: No, consider for example the Bernoulli random variable $X$ and the indicator function $1_{\text{X is equal to 0}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. For instance, for $X = \mathbf{1}_F$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mathbf{1}_F] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_F^2] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_F] = \mathbb{P}(F) \neq \mathbb{P}(F)^2 = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_F] \mathbb{P}(F) = \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{P}(F)
$$
whenever the probability of $F$ is outside $\{0,1\}$. In fact, when $X = \mathbf{1}_G$ the conclusion is only true when $F$ and $G$ are *independent*.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is the number of heads you get when you toss a coin (thus either $0$ or $1$) and $F$ is the event that you get a head.  Then $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \mathbb{1}_{\{F\}} \right]$ is $1/2$ and $\mathbb{E} [X]P(F)$ is $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

What is true in general is that 
$$
E[X1_F] = E[E[X |F]1_F] = P(F) E[X |F] $$

but if $F$ is not independent of $X$ there is no equality in general.